# Angular JS unable to get param values

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Hello I am trying to fetch data of specific user using php and AngularJS but the AngularJS is not adding Params in my code I tried all the ways but nothing works for me, I dont know what wrong in it I am using HTTP.GET procedure

**Here is my JS code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('pages/modVehiclePayments/getPendingPO.php', {
        params: {
            source: link,
            getvendornumber: user.phonenum
        }
     }).success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 50; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

**Here is my PHP**

```
$VendorNum = $_GET['getvendornumber'];

$query="SELECT * FROM tblvendors WHERE VendorNo='$VendorNum' AND statuscode='2'";

$result = $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);
$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}
# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

Comment: Have you logged out data ($scope.list)? Is it what you expect, except minus the params you expect?

Comment: make sure your angular version is below 1.6. `success` does't work above version 1.6

Comment: Put 'console.dir(data) or console.log(data)' in success fucntion and share output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have invoke the array data from `select` query like this.

**Php:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblvendors WHERE VendorNo='$VendorNum' AND statuscode='2'";
```

and return the value as **json** format.

```
 return json_encode($query);
```

**Angularjs**

```
$http.get('pages/modVehiclePayments/getPendingPO.php').then(function (res) {
          $scope.data = res.data; 
});
console.log($scope.data)
```

Comment: this is now what I am getting `SyntaxError: missing : after property id
 

$http.get({'pages/modVehiclePayments/getPendingPO.php').success(function(res){`

Comment: Actaully I am trying to select data using WHERE Clause and I want to load data using that its not sending the variable value using GET my url will be like this **pages/modVehiclePayments/getPendingPO.php?getvendornumber=VAC-11700000001** but its not working

Comment: Stop using "success".here Use this: $http.get('path').then(function (res){ success msg },function (res){ error  msg});

Comment: Perfect but the problem is now I am getting `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: getvendornumber in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\pakmotor\administration\pages
\modVehiclePayments\getPendingPO.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
[]` No value of getvendornumber is sent how can i forward textbox value

Comment: Go and check the error on getPendingPo.php in 5th line. Or show me the 5th line of coding.

Comment: here is the fifth line: **$VendorNum = $_GET['getvendornumber'];**

Comment: I noticed that `ng-model="user.phonenum"` is not getting any value but its value is undefined if I can load its value automatically it wont create problem

Comment: In this case, you have to use $http.post and In php Remove $_GET into $_POST

Comment: Use this link for your reference:https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136984/discussion-between-object-and-rtra).

Comment: OK I am there on chat

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think your php return a "painText".
Try to fetch your data with a `JSON.parse` or try to add a JSON header in your php.

```
 $scope.list = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Can you log `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: i tried with the php file its loading JSON data properly